# how can partion of single hardisk after install ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, gparted

i have new dell laptop with Ubuntu window with single drive 1 Tb so how can part ion in three drive without any risk of my system data

Answer (score 0):

You could use GParted Live to partition your storage.

http://gparted.org/download.php